# How to add to an XML programatically by adding another View?

Tags: android, xml, programmatically-created

I am making an app similar in design to a Reddit/YouTube/Yahoo News app, it uses the API's to gather information on recent posts.

When you start the app, it displays all the recent posts exactly like this:

http://wpuploads.appadvice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/screen1136x1136-68-576x1024.jpeg

The goal is to make all posts conform to a match_parent width and wrap_content height (max 300 dp height) and - just like the picture linked above - make all the posts conform to one look; Title on the top, body/picture in the middle and number of comments underneath.

Let's say my common View layout is something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lesson 1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#8c8c8c"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:background="@drawable/lesson1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10 Comments"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I want to replicate this Layout style (Text, Image, Text) every time there is a new post and add it to the existing XML. How would I do this?

Comment: This can be done using list view OR recycler view, with custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

You would use a LayoutInflater to inflate the xml file into a View.  Then you would add that view to the layout wherever you want it.